# The fastest way to find an obtuse triangle based on several sets of lengths

Tags: triangles

A question from ACT math:
[image]

I'm wondering except using the law of cosine to get the answer K, is there any faster way to figure it out?

Comment: Hint : If $c$ is the largest side, we must have $a^2+b^2<c^2$

Comment: In this case, J is also a obtuse triangle?

Comment: You had the right idea. The cosine law is in fact the key. The numerator is negative if and only if $a^2+b^2<c^2$ in which case we get a negative cosine leading to an angle exceeding $90$°

Comment: $7^2+10^2=149>144=12^2$ , so no

Comment: Don't forget to show that we have a triangle with the given sides at all, which is however easy to check.

Answer (score 1):

If $\angle A$ is an obtuse angle in a triangle.

$$90<\angle A<180, -1<\cos\angle A<0$$

$$\cos\angle A= \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc} <0$$

using only numerator since denominator is always positive

$$a^2>b^2+c^2$$

where $a$ is the longest side

$$16^2>11^2+8^2$$

Comment: This is exactly how we get the criterion, but $0<cos(\alpha)<-1$ is the wrong double- inequality.